# How to properly debug ThreadPool?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

I'm trying to get some data from a web page. To speed up this process (they allow me to make 1000 requests per minute), I use `ThreadPool`.

Since there is a huge amount of data, the process is quite vulnerable to connection fails etc. so I try to log everything I can to be able to detect each mistake I did in code.

The problem is that program sometimes just stops without any exception (it acts like it is running but with no effect - I use PyCharm). I log catched exceptions everywhere I can but I can't see any exception in any log.

I assume that if there were a timeout reached, the exception would be raised and logged.

I've found out where the problem could be. Here is the code:

As a pool, I use: `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool`
And lock: `from threading import Lock`

The download_category function is being used in loop.

```
    def download_category(url):
        # some code
        #
        # ...

        log('Create pool...')
        _pool = Pool(_workers_number)

        with open('database/temp_produkty.txt') as f:
            log('Spracovavanie produktov... vytvaranie vlakien...') # I see this in log
            for url_product in f:
                x = _pool.apply_async(process_product, args=(url_product.strip('\n'), url))
            _pool.close()
            _pool.join()

            log('Presuvanie produktov z temp export do export.csv...') # I can't see this in log
            temp_export_to_export_csv()
            set_spracovanie_kategorie(url)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception('Got exception on download_one_category: {}'.format(url))
```

And process_product function:

```
def process_product(url, cat):
    try:
        data = get_product_data(url)
    except:
        log('{}: {} exception while getting product data... #') # I don't see this in log
        return
    try:
        print_to_temp_export(data, cat) # I don't see this in log
    except:
        log('{}: {} exception while printing to csv... #') # I don't see this in log
        raise
```

LOG function:

```
def log(text):
    now = datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
    _lock.acquire()
    mLib.printToFile('logging/log.log', '{} -> {}'.format(now, text))
    _lock.release()
```

I use `logging` module too. In this log, I see that probably 8 (number of workers) times request was sent but no answer hasn't been recieved.

EDIT1:

```
def get_product_data(url):
    data = defaultdict(lambda: '-')

    root = load_root(url)
    try:
        nazov = root.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()')[0]
    except:
        nazov = root.xpath('//h1/text()')[0]

    under_block = root.xpath('//h2[@id="lowest-cost"]')

    if len(under_block) < 1:
        under_block = root.xpath('//h2[contains(text(),"Naj")]')
        if len(under_block) < 1:
            return False

    data['nazov'] = nazov
    data['url'] = url

    blocks = under_block[0].xpath('./following-sibling::div[@class="shp"]/div[contains(@class,"shp")]')

    i = 0

    for block in blocks:
        i += 1
        data['dat{}_men'.format(i)] = eblock.xpath('.//a[@class="link"]/text()')[0]

    del root
    return data
```

LOAD ROOT:

```
class RedirectException(Exception):
    pass

def load_url(url):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    if r.status_code == 301:
        raise RedirectException
    if r.status_code == 404:
        if '-q-' in url:
            url = url.replace('-q-','-')
            mLib.printToFileWOEncoding('logging/neexistujuce.txt','Skusanie {} kategorie...'.format(url))
            return load_url(url) # THIS IS NOT LOOPING 
        else:
            mLib.printToFileWOEncoding('logging/neexistujuce.txt','{}'.format(url))
    html = r.text
    return html


def load_root(url):
    try:
        html = load_url(url)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception('load_root_exception')
        raise
    return etree.fromstring(html, etree.HTMLParser())
```

Comment: So obviously get_product_data is where things are hanging - can you show the code or at least a runnable example (including the URL you are accessing) that exhibits the problem. Maybe it isn't hanging, so much as waiting for a response. Does your code work against any other website?

Comment: @barny Thanks for the comment, I've added the code to the question.

Comment: So does it ever get past requests.get() - is that where it hangs? You say this website supposedly allows 1000 requests/second, how many can it process in parallel or is it one-at-a-time? What is the website?

Comment: I was thinking about that. I think that it would raise TimeoutException after several seconds, wouldn't it?

Comment: Say you reduce the threads to 1 your code should still work only more slowly. Does it work? At what rate does it collect data?

Comment: The problem is that this situation happens randomly. After 6 minutes up to after 2 hours so I can't just checking it.

Comment: So it appears there's nothing obvious with your code that is the problem if it can work for 2 hours. It is the interaction with the website that is the problem, perhaps the website itself. Try reducing the threads to 1 - does it still happen? If not, increase to 2, does it still happen?